# Convert unsigned long to float with 2 precision decimal value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert the value to float with 2 precision decimal format.

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lu", (unsigned long)users.count];
float totalRatingCount = atof([formattedNumber UTF8String]);
```

This gives me values such as

```
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
```

What I want is the following

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A float has no precision value, it's not a fixed point value. However, there is an easier way to convert to float:

`CGFloat totalRating = [formattedNumber floatValue];`

to print a float with 2dp's of precision, use the format string `@"%.02f"`

Comment: you have to format it, like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", totalRating]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%.2f` format specifier as

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", (float)users.count];
float totalRatingCount = atof([formattedNumber UTF8String]);
```

and you'll get the desired out put with 2 values precision after decimal.

Comment: I am printing the result in NSLog, and it still shows me the value as "2.000000"

Comment: NSLog(@"formattedNumber = %@", formattedNumber); it will print value as "2.00"

Answer (score 1):

```
Using NSNumberFormatter, you can rounding number up to two digit.
double d = 12.1278;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(d)];

NSLog(@"numberString: %@", numberString);
```

Output is :

**numberString: 12.12**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(unsigned long)users.count];
NSNumberFormatter* nf=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
nf.minimumFractionDigits=2;
nf.maximumFractionDigits=2;
NSString* str = [nf stringFromNumber:number];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```